# ¿Como ordenar aleatoriamente pero equitativamente un arreglo de strings en java?

Tags: java, random

No he logrado encontrar una manera de poder ordenar un arreglo de strings de manera aleatoria un numero n de veces. Pero al final debe los strings deben aparecer la misma cantidad de veces en la lista.

Osea, como puedo lograr ordenar aleatoriamente de 8 (o "x") maneras diferentes un arreglo de strings?

Aqui va mi codigo:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Organizador {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*** MODULO CAPTURA ***/
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
       System.out.println("Ingrese el aforo del aula: ");
       int aforo = scan.nextInt();
       //System.out.println("Ingrese la fecha de inicio de la clase (dd/mm/yyy): ");
       //Date clase = new Date();
 
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de estudiantes: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        String[] estudiantes = new String[size];
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: " +(i+1));
            estudiantes[i]=scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Ingrese el número de listas que desea crear: ");
        int numeroListas = scan.nextInt(); 
        for(int i = 0; i<numeroListas;i++){
            String[] listafinal = organizarRandom(estudiantes, aforo);
             System.out.println("Lista asistencia semana "+(i+1)+ ":");
 
             for(int j=0; j<aforo; j++){
           System.out.println(listafinal[j]);
       }
        }
 
 
 
    }
     /*** MODULO ACTUADOR ***/
    public static String[] organizarRandom(String[] array, int n) {
 
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
    for (String i : array)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
 
    String[] answer = new String[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        answer[i] = list.get(i);
 
    return answer;
 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear índices aleatorios entre 0 y `array.length -1` y luego intercambiar los elementos en esos índices y hacer ese proceso `n` veces:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(organizarRandom(new String[]{"hola", "adios", "perro", "gato"},10 )));
    }

    public static String[] organizarRandom(String[] array, int n) {
        
        int randomIndex;
        String temp;
        Random r = new Random();
        
        // hacer el ordenamiento aleatorio n veces
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) 
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            // generar numero aleatorio entre 0 y array.length
            randomIndex = r.nextInt(array.length); 
            // hacer el intercambio entre la palabra en posicion i y randomIndex
            temp = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = temp;
        }

        return array;

    }
}
```